# XP1 Installation Question for DDS and cm-secondary

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I am preparing me for my first XP1 Installation and I only have One CD and one CM in my setup.

- For what is the "sitecore-xp1-dds.json" for. whats the usage of this configuration JSON and when do I need to install it?
- and when do I need to install the "sitecore-XP1-cm-dds-patch.json"?
- and when do I have to install the cm-secondary Json file? (I think only when I have more then one CM)
- Do I have to install a SOLr Zookeeper or can I just pass nothing into the "SolrZookeeperUrl" parameter? Is this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For what is the "sitecore-xp1-dds.json" for. whats the usage of this configuration JSON and when do I need to install it?

DDS stands for "Dedicated Dispatch Server".
It's used in EXM scaling scenarios.

> and when do I need to install the "sitecore-XP1-cm-dds-patch.json"?

`sitecore-XP1-cm-dds-patch.json` is used to patch CM instances so they will use the DDS instead of handling this role themselves.

> and when do I have to install the cm-secondary Json file? (I think only when I have more then one CM)

You are correct: it's used to install additional CM instances and will skip executing the DacPacs to create databases.